# Is there any way to display the arrow button on UINavigationbar without actually pushing a controller?

Tags: iphone

As titled. I need a way to display the arrow buttom on UINavigationbar without actually pushing a controller. The reason why I can't push a controller is because I need to keep the keyboard displayed while transitioning.

So to clarify: I start with a modal view controller (where there's nothing on the top left bar) like this -

[image]
<sub>(source: [iphonefaq.org](http://www.iphonefaq.org/images/archives/isms.jpg))</sub>

Then transition the top bar to one that looks like this -

[image]
<sub>(source: [gizmodo.com](http://cache.gizmodo.com/assets/images/gizmodo/2008/07/smsfreeiphone.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do this pretty easily.  Just set the leftBarButtonItem of your self.navigationItem to be a back button.

Comment: there is no way to create or set a "back" button. You can only create and set square buttons.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can do this by getting the `UINavigationItem` for the current screen. You can get it from the `topItem` property of the `UINavigationBar`.

Once you have the `UINavigationItem` that represents your current title are you should be able to experiment with the `backBarButtonItem` property, then call `setHidesBackButton:animated:` to show the back button.

Answer (score 0):

You can**not** dynamically change the backbutton on the UINavigationItem instance that belongs to the UIViewController instance that is currently being displayed. The backbutton that you will see displayed is the last one that was set before the UIViewController instance (and its UINAvigationItem) was pushed.

BUT, you can show/hide the backbutton. So how about setting the correct backbutton before the UIViewController instance is pushed and hiding it (viewControllerInstance.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;"). And then setting  "viewControllerInstance.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;" when you want to display the back button.

You can obviously dynamically change the UINavigationItems and their backbuttons on a UINavigationBar that you create yourself (i.e. one that does not belong to a UINavigationController).